# Returning index of an Array when it stops increasing and begins decreasing

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

having a problem when running two tests using this code, test 1 returns the whole array, test2 returns the appropriate index. (the point in the array in which it stops decreasing or increasing and starts the reverse) if there is only one sequence it should return -1

the test cases are
Input: [-4, -2, 9, 10]
Output: -1
Input: [5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 11]
Output: 3

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
      i++;
      if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
        return -1
      }
      else if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        return i
      }
    } while (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
      i++;
      if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
        return -1
      } else if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
        return i
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;

}
```

Comment: Why do you have so strange setup of returns here ? Return is supposed to go out of the function, but I don't see a function here. In particular after any return in first "while" loop succeedes, no other code is gonna be run. I think you may not understand how loops and functions (returns) really work.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the function in the example it was just - function ArrayChallenge(arr)
essentially if the array never changes from increasing to decreasing it should return -1, otherwise search for the index in which it switches. i am pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution below, the `isHomogeneous()` method returns true if the content of the array is ever-increasing or ever-decreasing. The `isIncreasing()` method returns true if the array content is constantly decreasing. The `isDecreasing()` method returns true if the array content is ever-increasing. The `getAscendingIndex()` method returns the index at which the contents of the array begin to decrease. The `getDescendingIndex()` method returns the index at which the contents of the array begin to decrease. The `application()` method contains application code that executes other methods. If the content of the array is not homogeneous (continuously increasing or decreasing), the first index value at which the values start to increase in an array that starts with decreasing values is obtained using the `getDescendingIndex()` method.

```js
/* Returns true if the array is descending to the elements (homogeneous). */
function isIncreasing(array) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i)
    if(array[i] < array[i + 1])
      return false;
  return true;
}

/* Returns true if the array is incremental (homogeneous) to the elements. */
function isDecreasing(array) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i)
    if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
      return false;
  return true;
}

/* Returns true if the array content is ever-increasing or ever-decreasing. */
function isHomogeneous(array) {
  return isIncreasing(array) || isDecreasing(array);
}

/* return the descending index in the array starting with increasing. */
function getAscendingIndex(array) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i)
    if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
      return i;
  return -1;
}

/* return increasing index in array starting with decreasing. */
function getDescendingIndex(array) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i)
    if(array[i] < array[i + 1])
      return i;
  return -1;
}

/* demo */
function application() {
  let firstArray = [-4, -2, 9, 10];
  let secondArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 11];
  
  console.log(`Increasing: ${(isIncreasing(firstArray) == true) ? "true" : "false"}`);
  console.log(`Decreasing: ${(isDecreasing(firstArray) == true) ? "true" : "false"}`);
  console.log(`First Array Index: ${getAscendingIndex(firstArray)}`);
  
 if(!isHomogeneous(secondArray) && getAscendingIndex(secondArray) != -1) {
    console.log(`Second Array Index: ${getDescendingIndex(secondArray)}`);
  }
}

application();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach would be useful:

Find the index of the maximum and minimum element.
Check if this index is the beginning or the end of the array and retern -1 if it is.
And last return the maximal index out of the found ones.

```js
  const first = [-4, -2, 9, 10];
  const second = [5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 11];
  
  const getMyIndex = (arr) => {
    const maxIndex = arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr));
    const minIndex = arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr));
    const getResult = (index) => 
      (index === 0) || (index === arr.length - 1) ? -1 : index;
    
    return Math.max(getResult(maxIndex), getResult(minIndex));   
  };
  
  console.log('arr:', first, 'result:', getMyIndex(first));
  console.log('arr:', second, 'result:', getMyIndex(second));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

java solution that works!!!hope you will find it useful

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
   int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3};
    boolean asc=false;
    boolean dsc=false;
    int n=arr.length;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]<arr[i-1]){
            x=i;
            break;
        }
        if(i==n-1){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i-1])
                asc=true;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i-1]){
            y=i;
            break;
        }
        if(i==n-1){
            if(arr[i]<arr[i-1])
                dsc=true;
        }
    }
    if(asc||dsc)
        System.out.println("-1");
    else{
        if(x>y)
           System.out.println("asc"+(x-1));
        else
            System.out.println("dsc"+(y-1));
    }    

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.